# jQuery form validate not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've spent hours on this and I have no idea why this jquery validate() doesn't work. I finally broke it down to minimum and it still doesn't work. This is the actuall code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).on("click", "#submit", function() {

            $("#form").validate({
                rules: {
                    input: { required: true}
                },
                messages: {
                    input: { required: "required" }
                },
                ignore:      "",
                errorClass:  'fieldError',
                onkeyup:     false,
                onblur:      false,
                errorElement:'label',
                submitHandler: function() {                        
                    alert("alert");
                }
            });

            return false;
         });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <form id="form">
        <input type="text" value="" name="input" id="input" />
    </form>
    <a href="#" id="submit">submit</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something obvious here? I get no errors and nothing happens when "submit" is clicked.

**UPDATE:** I have moved the validate() outside the "click" event into document "ready" event and now it fires off when the document is loaded outputting message in the console "nothing selected, can't validate, returning nothing"
This is not how I want it to work obviously, so how do I attach it to the click event?

**UPDATE 2:** Thanks to @NXT i finally make the validation run, however "submitHandler" is still not working and I need to use it to make Ajax call, because the form must be submitted without a page reload.

Comment: @ExplosionPills undelete yours dude - you beat me to it :)

Comment: I believe that `.validate` is not supposed to go in a callback.  Try moving it outside of the callback and wrapping it in `$(document).ready`

Comment: @ExplosionPills I guess that makes sense, however how do I trigger the validation when "submit" is pressed? The submit button in this case is a tag, not the actual form submit.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I deleted it because that's not the problem.  He's binding to the submit button using delegation, so it should trigger even though the button is loaded after the fact

Comment: @Caballero I'm not 100% sure how `.validate` works, but I assume that is handled automatically (i.e. it does the validation checking whenever the form submit event is triggered by anything).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you intentionally put the submit button outside the form? I modified it, to submit the form when clicked.
It works now - the validation message appears, and the alert message too (when you submit the form with some content). Either use the code parts below, or try it online - http://jsfiddle.net/Vcmfs/

Head:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#form").validate({
                rules: {
                    input: { required: true}
                },
                messages: {
                    input: { required: "required" }
                },
                ignore:      "",
                errorClass:  'fieldError',
                onkeyup:     false,
                onblur:      false,
                errorElement:'label',
                submitHandler: function() {                        
                    alert("alert");
                }
            });

        $("#submit").click(function(){
            $("#form").submit();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Body:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" value="" name="input" id="input" />
</form>
<a href="#" id="submit">submit</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to make the validation work now, however the submitHandler does not fire, which is essential for my script to work.

Comment: @Caballero It should work when validation is successful, just write anything in the box and it should fire :)

Comment: Yes I did exactly that, still submitHandler is not responding. This is beyond frustrating.

Comment: @Caballero I added a link to jsFiddle code, I simply copied the parts from above and they work for me in Firefox, IE 10 and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, this time it worked. Just had to change .valid() to .submit()

Comment: Thanks! I never knew you had to add another event handler to the submit button to fire the validate() submitehandler. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 6):

[`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) doesn't actually perform the validation, it configures the form for validation.

If you change your submit link to a submit button `<input type='submit' value='Submit'/>`, it will work as expected.

Another option is to call [`.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) in your link click handler, which will trigger validation.

See this fiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/v5HQr/1/

Comment: Thanks, your answer did nudge me in the right direction. I still can't make submitHandler to do anything though...